# Logging not working for additional tomcat instances

Tags: apache, tomcat, logging, tomcat7

I have a tomcat installation that is the default one. This is also setup to start automatically when my system starts. This default installation can be started or stopped with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start | stop | restart
```

Logging works for this installation.

I also have 2 other tomcats (other version of tomcat7 installed on this system). Both of these instances are installed in the project workspaces. These tomcat instances are added to projects using the Servers view. Logging does not work for them at all. (I can't find anything if I look into their logs folders). What do I need to change to activate logging for these installations.

Comment: Just as a wild guess... Do these additional instances use the same user als the main one? Do they log into the same directory? If not, could it be an issue of insuficient access privileges on these directories or of the other users?

Comment: @Nicktar Yes. All of them are under the same user. I really need different tomcats for various projects.

Comment: @Nicktar they don't log into same directory...only the one that starts automatically logs anything in the first place. The other 2 instances simply don't log anything in the logs folders or /var/log/tomcat. They do show things in the console view but simply don't log anything in the log folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the configuration of the DailyRollingFileAppender you can have a look at the answer for this question: [log4j properties DailyRollingFileAppender does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928972/log4j-properties-dailyrollingfileappender-does-not-work) or other similar posts.

In order to check if the log4j configuration is really read or not, you can turn on debugging by adding this parameter in the start configuration:

```
-Dlog4j.debug
```

The appender should work as soon as this is activated. Check your home folder or your logs folder to see if it works.

You can essentially add this type of appender for each extra Tomcat you have in your configuration.